# Non-ECMAscript code for function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm reading through the [ECMA Script 2015 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-terms-and-definitions-function).

Under `functions` I see:

> In addition to its properties, a function contains executable code and state that determine how it behaves when invoked. **A function’s code may or may not be written in ECMAScript** *(emphasis added)*.

Under what circumstances would a function's code not be written in ECMA script?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The native functions provided by the execution environment (like the `String` and `Array` classes, or `setTimeout`, or the browser DOM) are frequently written (or powered by other functions written) in C.

Comment: Whats confusing to me about this is there is a section directly underneath function for 'built-in functions', where it says " Examples of built-in functions include parseInt and Math.exp. An implementation may provide implementation-dependent built-in functions that are not described in this specification."  This looks to be distinct from the previous "function" section.

Comment: @juwiley: Most hosts provide other functions that are not covered by the ECMAScript spec (eg, the DOM, or `console`).

Comment: Here is some reading material for those interested in if and how they can write these kinds of functions themselves (for Node): [1](https://github.com/kkaefer/node-cpp-modules), [2](http://syskall.com/how-to-write-your-own-native-nodejs-extension/), [3](http://joseoncode.com/2012/04/10/writing-your-first-native-module-for-node-dot-js-on-windows/), [4](http://kkaefer.github.com/node-cpp-modules/), [5](http://nkzawa.tumblr.com/post/46089897239/how-to-write-native-node-addons).

Answer (score 9):

> Under what circumstances would a function's code not be written in ECMA script?

Core functions provided by the JavaScript engine. E.g. `Array.prototype.find`:

```
> Array.prototype.find
find() { [native code] }
```

For example V8, Chrome's JavaScript engine, is implement in C++, so that method is implemented in C++.

Comment: I think that there are many functions written in (privileged) javascript in the V8 implementation which are still stringified to `[native code]`